# Import Internal Error during ImportXML with Google Spreadsheet even without /tbody

Tags: xml, google-sheets, web-scraping, xpath, google-sheets-formula

I am trying to import some data table from
http://www.klse.my/stock/entitlement/dividend/7087.jsp#stockDetailDiv
and link from
http://www.bursamalaysia.com/market/listed-companies/company-announcements/#/?category=EA&company=7087
website to my Google spreadsheet, but Google sheet keep gives me Import Internal Error.

```
=IMPORTXML("http://www.klse.my/stock/entitlement/dividend/7087.jsp#stockDetailDiv","//*[@id='entitlementTable']/tr[2]/td")    

=IMPORTXML("http://www.bursamalaysia.com/market/listed-companies/company-announcements/#/?category=EA&company=7087","//*[@id='bm_ajax_container']/div/table/tr/td[4]/a/@href")
```

I really do not know what causes this problem, but I used to overcome it playing with the xpath query and delete /tbody. This time I couldn't find a xpath query which works.

Does any programming expert know the reason of this error, or how can I make it work?

Answer (score 0):

this should work - it pulls in the table:

```
=IMPORTHTML("http://www.klse.my/stock/entitlement/dividend/7087.jsp#stockDetailDiv","table",1)
```

or also this:

```
=IMPORTXML("http://www.klse.my/stock/entitlement/dividend/7087.jsp#stockDetailDiv","//tr")
```

Some of what is causing the difficulty of pulling it in, often is due to jquery being loaded after the page loads - it is dynamic, not static or permanent in the html itself.

Answer (score -1):

Try to use

```
=IMPORTXML("https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moon_landing"; "//a/@href") (semicolon)
instead
=IMPORTXML("https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moon_landing", "//a/@href")
```

Official documentation: https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093342?hl=en

Comment: Hi.. Thanks for help, but I still get the same error :(